# git error: RPC failed; HTTP 502 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 502 Proxy Error

Tags: git, https, proxy, repository

I work with tortoise git for my actual project. Me and the other members have some trouble since last week with our repository (worked perfect before).

When I want to push/pull/clone (HTTPS), I get the following error:

> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly error: RPC failed; HTTP 502
>   curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 502 Proxy Error

Seems like something went wrong with the proxy server. I can use the repository as usual in the local network of my institute, but I get no access from home.

Does anyone has an idea how to fix this error? Unfortunately i can't find any other posts about this problem.

Greetings, 
Homer

Answer (score 16):

This kind of error happens mostly because of 2 reasons:

1. pushing binary files/jar files to repo
2. if the file(s) size is big.

**Solution:**
1. Use admin credential for pushing code change
2. execute the command `git config --local http.postBuffer 157286400` before pushing.

Comment: You may need to increase the `postBuffer`. `157286400` bits = `19.6608` MByte. If your repo is bigger in size, increase it.

Comment: This is 150 MB. Divide it by 1024 twice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. git remote remove origin
2. git remote add origin URL

I don't understand why the error appears but luckily this works for me, i hope that can help others, regards.

Comment: While this is not an answer, Please use comment section to ask additional or supplementary question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first step in troubleshooting this is to determine if you can import the entire repository without problems. If so, then any individual branch within the repository should not cause a problem. So rather than trying to "just clone a branch", can you do the following:

1. Clone the source repository locally
2. Create a new repository on GitHub
3. Add the new repository as a remote for the local repository
4. Push the contents of the local repository to the new GitHub repository

Answer (score 0):

Updating http.postBuffer didn't work for me. In my case, I had 17 files to push. So I have pushed 17 files in chunks. Like 4-5 files together. It did solve my issue. Thanks @thesprinter for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I undid my last commit via `git resest` then again commit the changes. It resolved the problem.