# git error: RPC failed; HTTP 502 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 502 fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, https

I am suddenly having an unexpected error while trying to push in Git. Previously I was able to push, but now I`m receiving the following error:

```
error: RPC failed; HTTP 502 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 502
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I have tried the following, but the error still remains:

1- Increasing the Buffer size ([git error: RPC failed; HTTP 502 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 502 Proxy Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878840/git-error-rpc-failed-http-502-curl-22-the-requested-url-returned-error-502-pr))
2- Creating a new repo
3- Reinstalling my local Git

Could you please give me any suggestions

Comment: Does your network have a proxy or TLS middlebox in use?  Are you using an antivirus or firewall on Windows other than the default one?  What server are you trying to push to?  Is it locally hosted or is it a well-known provider?

Comment: I`m trying to push to Azure (Kudu). VPN is off. I`m not sure for the proxy, but previously I was able to deploy. I have a data file 800 MB. Might this be an issue?

Comment: In addition, sometimes I get the error: fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: error in sideband demultiplexer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message means that some server between you and the ultimate destination server somewhere in Azure got an invalid response, timed out, or encountered an error.  That server is generically referred to in HTTP as a *proxy*, but it could be a normal HTTP or SOCKS proxy on your network, antivirus or firewall software on your computer, or a frontend machine on Azure Kudu.

It may very well be that putting an 800 MB blob in your repository is the cause of this; generally checking in large blobs into a Git repository is a bad idea, and such blobs should be stored in some object storage or artifact system.  It may also be that it is totally unrelated to that: it could be a temporary Azure error or some software on your computer or network that is temporarily broken or has a bug.  All we know from this response is that some machine in the middle encountered a problem.

You can try to strip out the large blob from your repository (including anywhere in the history) and see if that fixes it; you should probably do that regardless.  If it does not, you should try to run with `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE_CURL=1` to see if you can extract the error message from the stream to try to figure out what machine is misbehaving and what the problem might be.

Finally, as a general rule, increasing the `http.postBuffer` size does not fix push problems.  In order for that to work, you have to have a broken system that doesn't support HTTP/1.1 or doesn't support chunked transfer encoding properly.  While such systems do exist, they are rare, and the best solution is to fix or replace them since they generally cause serious problems for any software using them.  Unless you know that you are using such a broken system, changing that setting will almost certainly not help.

Comment: Yes, that's the syntax, and you need to use a POSIX shell (so Git Bash on Windows).